# How is the suggested price determine for commodity auctions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Although the details are a bit ambiguous, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72489/how-are-gem-prices-on-the-auction-house-determined) seems to focus on buying gems, and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68461/selling-gems-at-the-diablo-3-auction-house?rq=1) on selling them.  What I could not find in either of them was a specific detail I'm interested in with regard to the sales process of commodities in general.

When you list a commodity, the game will "recommend" a unit sales price for that commodity.  When using methods described in [agent86's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68473/21619) to the 2nd question, I can not determine any direct correlation to the "instantaneous buy price" or "10 sale average" price, and of course as he mentions the 24 hour stat seems bugged.

This "recommended" price often seems like a bad deal for the seller (if they are interested in profit), but I also suspect many sellers may just leave it as default - which is why I am very interested to understand how the number is generated.

Comment: I've found I can typically price my commodities at somewhat higher than the "market price" I'm given and still sell immediately, which seems to indicate that it's not just slightly undercutting the current auction (or demand is so high that my price is considered to be "reasonable" quickly?)

Comment: I guess Blizzard uses trends: Take the "current average price" and look at the trend. If it is falling then suggest a slightly lower price than the "current average price" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended price is always equal to the average price of the last 10 commodities sold, which you can see when searching for a commodity. It is the second gold value when searching if I remember correctly.

Comment: Well @SergeantMad I don't know whether I was blind, or the game changed, but I see you are right.  Welcome to the site by the way.  Incidentally, I see that the 1 day average seems to be working now too.  Yay!